# The boundedness of a linear operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $H$ be the collection of all absolutely continuous functions $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb C$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $f^{'}\in L^{2}(0,1)$. We have an inner product $\langle f,g\rangle=\int^1_0 f^{'}(t)\overline {g'(t)}\,dt$. Now we have a linear operator $L:H\rightarrow\mathbb C$ defined by $L(f)=f(t)$ for some $t\in (0,1)$.

I can prove that this $H$ with this inner product is in fact a Hilbert space.

My question is that how can we show that this $L$ is bounded？ More specifically, how can we show that $\int_{[0,1]}|f^{'}(t)|^{2}dt\leq c|f(t)|^{2}$ for some constant $c$. I think we may have to appeal to some tools in real analysis.

Additionally, since we have Risze Representation theorem, how can we find a $h_{0}$ such that $L(f)=\langle f,h_0\rangle$.

Comment: I believe that to show $L$ is bounded, you need instead the inequality $$|f(t)|=|L(f)|\leq C \|f\|_{H}=C\left(\int_{0}^{1}|f'(t)|^{2}\mathrm{d}t\right)^{1/2}.$$

Comment: Hint: consider a function $g\in H$, such that $g'(x)=1$ for $x\in[0,t]$ and $g'(x)=0$ for $x\in[t,1]$. Then $\langle f,g\rangle=$ ? This will automatically prove the boundedness of the linear functional $L_t(f)=f(t),t\in(0,1]$.

Comment: @YuriiSavchuk Your proof of boundedness is much slicker than mine, but I will leave mine up to show another approach just using ideas from calculus.

Answer (score 2):

$f(t)=f(0)+\int_{0}^{t}f'(s)\mathrm{d}s$ by the fundamental theorem of calculus, so by the condition $f(0)=0,$ we get that $f(t)=\int_{0}^{t}f'(s)\mathrm{d}s$. For nonzero $f$, if we let $A\subset[0,1]$ be such that $A=\{x\in[0,1]:|f'(x)|\leq 1\},$ we get \begin{align*}|f(t)|=\left|\int_{0}^{t}f'(s)\mathrm{d}s\right|&\leq \int_{0}^{t}|f'(s)|\mathrm{d}s\\&\leq \int_{0}^{1}|f'(s)|\mathrm{d}s\\&\leq \int_{A}\mathrm{d}s+\int_{A^{c}}|f'(s)|^{2}\mathrm{d}s\\&\leq \lambda(A)+\|f\|_{H}^{2}\leq 1+\|f\|_{H}^{2},\end{align*} where $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure. If we apply the same line of reasoning to $cf,$ $c>0,$ we get $c|f(t)|\leq \lambda(\{x\in[0,1]:c|f'(x)|\leq 1\})+c^{2}\|f\|_{H}^{2}\leq 1+c^{2}\|f\|_{H}^{2}.$ Then $|f(t)|\leq c^{-1}+c\|f\|_{H}^{2},$ and by choosing $c=\|f\|_{H}^{-1}$ (note that we chose $f\neq0$), we get $|f(t)|\leq \|f\|_{H}+\|f\|_{H}=2\|f\|_{H}.$